# How to prove or disprove “Necessarily P entails P” in Kripke Modal Logic?

Tags: modal-logic

I'm doing the body of exercises in Priest's Introduction to Non-classical logic, and got weirdly stuck on 2.12 (o). (I'm on Problems 2.12, if anyone has a link to the answers that would also be much appreciated; can't find them online.) The exercise is to "show" that it is not the case that it is not a logical truth that necessarily p entails p and the method is to construct a tableau.

I start by negating it. 
1) Not (necessarily p entails p). 
2) necessarily p, not p (from 1).

Then I can't get any further with tableaux methods at least.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is correct :

1) **¬(◻ P → P)**, i

2) **◻ P**, i

3) **¬P**, i

4) **P**, j --- from 2), where (i **R** j)

and we are stuck... there is no contradiction, provided that **R** is not *reflexive*, i.e. not-(i **R** i).

See [Modal Axioms and Conditions on Frames](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModAxiConFra) :

> the Axiom (M) **□A → A** corresponds to the Condition on Frames that **R** is Reflexive.